# Uniformizing background in scanned images

Tags: background, scanning, adobe-lightroom

I have some old photographs that I have scanned. While the image of the person is clear, the background has several blurs and is not a perfect black as one would desire.

Is there a way to detect the person's image alone as a separate object, thereby isolating it from the background? That way, I could get rid of all background noise. What is the technical jargon for this process? I searched for 'Object detection', but that leads me to engineering papers! Could someone point me to useful videos using Lightroom in this regard?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "object extraction." I know you can do this in Photoshop, but I am not a Lightroom user so I can't comment on if Lightroom allows pixel level editing which is needed to extract objects.

Comment: @Scott: Could you provide an answer pointing me to resources or procedure on object extraction in Photoshop?

Comment: Shyam, if you do a google search for "Photoshop object extraction" you will find literally thousands of tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do photo editing, such as extraction, compositing, retouching, etc. you still need a photo editor like Photoshop.

Lightroom is more an image management application, that has some limited edition capability but not enough for things like object extraction.